# Using QGIS, how can I add a bounding box attribute?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I have a shapefile where I am exporting the features to GeoJSON objects with ogr2ogr based on a simple where clause. One thing that I would like to be included in the GeoJSON object is the  'bbox' member (outlined [here](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#bounding-boxes)) , is it possible to add this as an attribute to the shapefile using QGIS?

I've done something similar with centroids and added the x/y as separate attributes. Are there any other ways to programmatically add this to my geojson files?

Comment: I've managed to solve my bounding box problem elsewhere, but I'd still love to know if it is possible to do this with QGIS!

Comment: It might be easier if you post the solution you figured out elsewhere and see if someone can adapt that solution to QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

With ogr2ogr you can use  -lco WRITE_BBOX=YES to output bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

@spatialthoughts is right and another way is that make your geojsons to GDAL Virtual Format and then add your bounding box to in  tags.

with gdalinfo you can get info about your vrt file. a nice addition to vrt is that it has ability to directly import into QGIS.

you can get some code in here about manually adding bbox [here](http://code.google.com/p/maptiler/source/browse/trunk/maptiler/gdalpreprocess.py?r=10).

```
            geotransform = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

            geotransform[0] = bbox[3]
            geotransform[1] = (bbox[2] - bbox[3]) / float(xsize)
            geotransform[2] = 0.0
            geotransform[3] = bbox[0]
            geotransform[4] = 0.0
            geotransform[5] = (bbox[1] - bbox[0]) / float(ysize)

            in_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
```

i hope it helps you...